# how to make submisison boxes work with sql/sqlite and flask,python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, flask, mysql-python

Ok so I'm making a test inventory system for myself where I submit each item manually, but I'm having trouble with the submissions. I have all the html and python worked out but when try to submit all of the things, an error pops up saying IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: posts.condition.

Here is my code:

App.py

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from models import create_post, get_posts

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        pass 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.form.get('post')
        item = request.form.get('item')
        TimenDate = request.form.get('TimenDate')
        condition = request.form.get('condition')
        history = request.form.get('history')

        create_post(item,TimenDate, condition, history)


    posts = get_posts()
    
   
    

    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

ABB.sql file :

```
    create table posts (
        id integer primary key autoincrement,
        item text not null,
        TimenDate text not null,
        condition text not null,
        history text not null
);
```

models.py file:

```
from os import path

ROOT = path.dirname(path.relpath((__file__)))

def create_post(item,TimenDate,condition, history):
    con = sql.connect(path.join(ROOT, 'database.db'))
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('insert into posts (item, TimenDate,condition, history) values( ?, ?, ?, ?)', (item, TimenDate, condition, history))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
 
def get_posts():
    con = sql.connect(path.join(ROOT, 'database.db'))
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('select * from posts')
    posts = cur.fetchall()
    return posts
```

my html file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action='/' role='form' method='POST'>
            <input placeholder='Item' name='item'>
            <input placeholder='TimenDate' name='TimenDate'>
            <input placeholder='Condition' name='Condition'>
            <input placeholder='History' name='History'>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div>{{ item[1] + ': ' + TimenDate[3]+ ': ' +Condition[5]+ ': ' +History[6]}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and finally the error:

```
create_post(item,TimenDate, condition, history)

File "/Users/mylaptop/ABB/models.py", line 9, in create_post
Open an interactive python shell in this framecur.execute('insert into posts (item, TimenDate,condition, history) values( ?, ?, ?, ?)', (item, TimenDate, condition, history))
```

thank you guys for any feedback. Im sure it has something to do with the abb.sql file and the database but I don't know what it is and why.

Answer (score 1):

You have several capitalization conflicts between what the form posts and what the route expects. For example

```
<input placeholder='Condition' name='Condition'>
```

and

```
condition = request.form.get('condition')
```

Comment: i tried that, but another error came back up. it says that  'item is undefined'. I think it has something to do with this code ```{% for post in posts %}
            <div>{{ item[1] + ': ' + TimenDate[2]+ ': ' +condition[3]+ ': ' +history[4]}}</div>
        {% endfor %}```

Comment: You're now on to a different category of errors. Try `post.item` instead of `item[1]`. Likewise with the other data items.

Comment: UndefinedError: 'tuple object' has no attribute 'item'